# Updating AngularJS fields based on other fields

Tags: angularjs

I have a series of input fields that are all bound to properties on an AngularJS model that are all editable.

Some of the fields are optionally calculated fields based on the other user input, a sample of the kind of input I'm working with can be found [here](http://jsbin.com/ONOZOQAQ/1/edit).

Basically if someone enters a value in the `time` and `distance` it should automatically work out `speed`, or `speed` and `distance` will work out time, and so on.

Comment: You can use `$watch` to fire a callback whenever user changes `time` or `distance` and update other values accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is underspecified since what if all the three values are specified by the user and he changes one of them? I took a guess and decided to change the last value which was touched by the user, keeping the recent two values constant.

I think it can be generalised for pretty much any formula, but your milage may vary. It was amusing to write. :)

Here is a working example: http://jsbin.com/OsuMaSek/1/edit

```js
$scope.time = 0;
$scope.distance = 0;
$scope.speed = 0;

$scope.touchOrder = {
  speed: 0,
  distance: 0,
  time: 0
};

function getLastTouched() {
  var minTouched = null, minVal = Infinity;
  Object.keys($scope.touchOrder).forEach(function (k) {
    if (minVal > $scope.touchOrder[k]) {
      minVal = $scope.touchOrder[k];
      minTouched = k;
    }
  });
  return minTouched;
}

$scope.totalTouchCount = 0;
$scope.touched = function (valTouched) {
  $scope.totalTouchCount++;

  $scope.touchOrder[valTouched] = $scope.totalTouchCount;

  if ($scope.totalTouchCount >= 2) {
    switch(getLastTouched()) {
      case 'time': $scope.time = $scope.distance / $scope.speed; break;
      case 'distance': $scope.distance = $scope.time * $scope.speed; break;
      case 'speed': $scope.speed = $scope.distance / $scope.time; break;
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Yeah I can see monitoring the change being an ideal way to track it.

And I do realise that if the user enters into all three fields strange things can happen, but it's likely that the user should enter speed _or_ distance, not both (and if they do we override).

Comment: @Slace I think it is quite a nice model to allow user to enter any field but it works better when there are only two fields (unit conversion, for example) instead of three. With three fields, it is difficult to figure out which field does the user _expect_ to update. If you _fix_ time, it would work out nicely.

Answer (score 1):

You can write something like that (by using `$watch`):

*JS*

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope) {

  $scope.mymodel = {};

  $scope.mymodel.time = 0;
  $scope.mymodel.distance = 0;
  $scope.mymodel.speed = 0;


   $scope.$watch(function () {
    return $scope.mymodel;
},
function (newValue, oldValue) {
    $scope.mymodel.speed = (newValue.distance > 0) ? newValue.distance / newValue.time : 0;
}, true);

});
```

**HTML**

```
 Time: <input type="number" ng-model="mymodel.time" />
  <br />
  Distance: <input type="number" ng-model="mymodel.distance" />
  <br />
  Speed: <input type="number" ng-model="mymodel.speed" />
```

*Comment*

Its only example, in this case you can't change velocity (speed).

Changed <kbd>[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/uzUVeQu/1/)</kbd>

**[EDIT]**

you can *play* with `$watch` to control sub-fields:

```
$scope.$watch(function () {
    return $scope.mymodel;
},
function (newValue, oldValue) { 

  if(newValue.speed != oldValue.speed){   
    $scope.mymodel.time = newValue.distance / newValue.speed;
    $scope.mymodel.distance =newValue.time *newValue.speed;
  }
  else if(newValue.distance != oldValue.distance){   
       $scope.mymodel.speed = (newValue.distance > 0) ? newValue.distance / newValue.time : 0;
  }
   else if(newValue.time != oldValue.time){   
      $scope.mymodel.speed = (newValue.distance > 0) ? newValue.distance / newValue.time : 0;
  }


}, true);
```

<kbd>[Demo 2](http://jsbin.com/uzUVeQu/2/edit)</kbd>